# Scrapping conponents from an iphone

Tags: iphone

I have an iphone 4 that no longer works.  I know that selling it is always an option, but i'm curious if i can scrap spare parts from it instead (especially sensors). I've looked online, but haven't found any evidence of any DIY instructions on how to do this.  I suspect that doing this is extremely difficult, if possible/worth it at all.

How difficult would it be to extract components from an iphone?  What equipment would i need to do this?  Weighing in the cost-benefit of scraping components, is it worth it?

Comment: No. It's most definitely not worth it.

Comment: The screen. Battery. Maybe the jack. Nothing else.

Comment: If it's a phone that belonged to someone else you might be able to steal all kinds of personal information. If it's yours, you might want to think twice about selling it. *Someone* might be able to get it working. Think of it as a filing cabinet full of personal documents with a sticky latch.

Comment: Most of the sensors would be in ultra tiny packages so that's a challenge right there, they may also be using unlabelled or NDA obfuscated parts, check out the iFixit iPhone 4 teardown, that'll have list of most of the parts and you can decide from that whether it's worth pursuing further

Answer (score 4):

Very small scale, undocumented parts. You'd need smd desoldering tools, and then spend days on trying to figure out how it maybe works. Not worth it.